# $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}_l$ is not continuous

Tags: general-topology

My book says that $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}_l$, given by $f(x) = x$, where $\mathbb{R}$ is the lower limit topology (that is, its basis elements are of the form $[a,b))$ is not continuous. It says that the inverse image is $[a,b)$ which is not open in $\mathbb{R}$.

Is it because it's impossible to write an open set $(a,b)$ in $\mathbb{R}$ by arbitrary unions and intersections of $[a,b)$?

Then, the book also says that $f:\mathbb{R}_l\to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous. Is it because the inverse takes $(a,b)$ to $(a,b)$ which are open in $\mathbb{R}_l$ because we can write $(a,b)$ as a union of finite intersections of sets $[a,b)$? If so, how's this union? Let me try:

$$\cup_{i\in \mathbb{N}}\left[a+\frac{1}{n},b\right) = (a,b)$$

Am I rigth?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Other way around: we can't write $[a, b)$ in $\Bbb R$ by arbitrary unions of $(c, d)$.

A function is continuous if the preimage of each open set is open. We know that $[a, b)$ is open in $\Bbb R_l$, and its preimage is $[a, b) \subseteq \Bbb R$. This set is not open in $\Bbb R$.

Also, your union looks correct. Any point $c \in (a, b)$ will have some $n$ for which $c - a \ge \frac{1}{n}$. So $a + \frac{1}{n} \le c$, and so $c$ is contained in one of the elements of your union.